# Adding rows to table in container with overflow:auto increases height of container

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a table in it. The div is set to overflow:auto. Rows can be added dynamically to the table. The div is a flex item in a parent with flex-direction:column, it is set to take up 80% of the height.

```
                    <div class="tableWrapper">
                    <table id="second" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            ...
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            ...
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
```

```
.tableWrapper{
    flex-basis:80%; /* This is the height */
    overflow-y:auto;
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
}

table{
    width:100%;
}

th{
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}

th, td{
    height:3em;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

The table starts empty with data being added. When the number of rows exceeds the height/flex basis of the container, the container both overflows with a scroll bar and grows in height. I am usually adding rows ~5 or 6 at a time.

This is in Firefox & Opera.
Safari on iPad OS handles it as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, forgot the rule-that-totally-makes-sense.

Applying overflow:hidden on the parent element of the page of course fixed the overflow problem with flexbox.